# Output correct alignment

Tags: c, printf

I have written a code, and it gives me the exact output that I want except for one thing, the `alignment` of integers in the output is from left to right but I need it to be from right to left.

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

 int cols, rows, i,j,num;

 scanf("%d %d",&rows, &cols);


 for (i=1; i<=1; i++){

     for (j=0; j<=cols; j++){

     if (j==0) printf("\t ");

      else {

        num=j;

        printf("\t%d", num);

      }

    }

    printf("\n");

  }


  for (i=2; i<=rows; i++){

    for (j=0; j<=cols; j++){

      if (j==0) num=i;

      else num=power(i,j);


      printf("\t%d", num);

      }

   printf("\n");

   }



   return 0;
}
```

---

The output that I am getting is

[image: My output]

---

The required output is

[image: Required Output]

Comment: Use field width specifiers in the printf format specifiers instead of trying to explicitly pad with white space.

Comment: No, no more screenshots of text!

Comment: `"\t%d"` --> `"%8d"`, `printf("\t ");` --> `printf("%8s", "");`

Answer (score 1):

Use e.g. `%6d` in the `printf()` format specifier, and don't use tabs.

See [the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) for the format specifier syntax. Field width is a standard feature.